# In C++, how do I run two syntactic commands at the same time?

Tags: c++

I'm making an Atari Pong game on Ubuntu with the Terminal.
I want to:

1. Get user input from keyboard(either "a", which moves the board to the left, or "d", which moves the board to the right)
2. Print the screen

Currently, I take the keyboard input and then print the screen, which results in a blank screen when waiting for keyboard input.

I tried:

```
#include <unistd.h>
pid_t pid = fork();
```

(in C++), and it kind of solved my problem, but it produced another problem where the board keeps resetting to its original place defined initially in my code.

Are there any libraries/techniques which can "multi-task" code?

Comment: _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. "_

Comment: You need seperate threads.  You need a disaply thread and an input thread and they need to communicate together.  That way when the input thread is waiting for input the display thread can still be drawing to the screen.

Comment: you shouldn't need threads. find  different way to get keyboard input that won't clear the screen.

Comment: Nah, go multiprocess directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a Pong style game in the terminal, you will want to use the `ncurses` library. There, you can write a *game loop* that looks something like this:

```
#include <curses.h>

while (true) {
    int k = getch();
    // Determine whether k is a keypress or not, and take action if so.
    // Update game display
}
```

The [`getch()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getch) function can check for keyboard input without stopping to wait for it.